# php regex to split string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "{It|This} part, but also {spin|rotation} the words";
```

i want to split `{It|This}` and `{spin|rotation}` to `It, This ,spin,rotation` by regular expression.

I need regular expression for this.

```
$str = "{It|This} part, but also {spin|rotation} the words";
$pattern =''; // need a pttern here
$arr = preg_split($pattern,$str);
print_r($arr);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation :

Using `preg_match_all()` the content between the `{` and `}` are matched and those matches are cycled through via a `foreach` , exploding the argument by `|` and then finally doing an `implode()`

#### The code..

```
$str = "{It|This} part, but also {spin|rotation} the words";
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $str, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $v)
{
    $new_val[]=explode('|',$v);
}
echo $new_val=implode(',',call_user_func_array('array_merge',$new_val));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
It,This,spin,rotation
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/144111)</kbd>